# Angular2 Stripe integration stripeResponseHandler cannot access this

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, payment

I'm integrating Stripe payments with Angular2 (actually Ionic but the code is the same)

the call to `Stripe.card.createToken` is successful and returns a token

but in `stripeResponseHandler` which is an async callback, I cannot access any of the "this" variables. for example I cannot set this.amount = 10 and I cannot call `this._http.post`

how can I access the "this" variables ? I'm trying to http post the token and the amount to an API to make the payment

```
  constructor(private _navController: NavController,
    private _http: Http) {   }

  submitPayment() {
    Stripe.setPublishableKey(this.key);
    this.card = new Card();
    this.card.number = this.cardNumber;
    this.card.cvc = this.cardCVC;
    this.card.exp_month = this.cardExpMonth;
    this.card.exp_year = this.cardExpYear;
    this.card.address_zip = this.cardAddressZip;

    try {
      Stripe.card.createToken(this.card, this.stripeResponseHandler);
    }
    catch (e) {
      alert(e.message);
    }

    // Prevent the form from being submitted:
    return false;   
  }

  stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {

    if (response.error) { // Problem!
      alert(response.error);

    } else { // Token was created!

      // Get the token ID:
      alert(response.id);

      try {

        this.amount = 10;

        let payment = new Payment();
        payment.token = response.id;
        payment.amount = this.amount;

        let body = JSON.stringify(payment);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        this._http.post(this.url, body, options)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
      }
      catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
      }

    }   
  }

  handleError(error: Response) {
    // may send the error to some remote logging infrastructure
    // instead of just logging it to the console
    console.error(error);
    alert('error' + error.text + " " + error.statusText);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');   
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just pass the function reference, then JavaScript doesn't keep the `this` reference. You have to take care of this explicitely:

Instead of

```
Stripe.card.createToken(this.card, this.stripeResponseHandler);
```

use

```
Stripe.card.createToken(this.card, (status, person) => this.stripeResponseHandler(status, person));
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

or

```
Stripe.card.createToken(this.card, this.stripeResponseHandler.bind(this));
```